# $(0,..,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$is is not a regular value of f

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

This question is from my assignment on submanifolds and I couldn't solve this particular question.

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be given by $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)= ({x_2}^2,...,{x_n}^2)$. Show that $(0,0,...,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is not a regular value of f but still $f^{-1}${$(0,...,0)$} is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension 1.

I have proved that $f^{-1}${$(0,...,0)$} is a submanifold but I am not able to prove other part.

Attempt:  $df (x_1,...,x_n)= (2x_2,...,2x_n)$  and I think it is a regular value because (0,...,0) = f(x,0,...0) ,$x\in \mathbb{R}$ .

So, what mistake I am making it this?

Comment: What’s the definition of regular value?  Does that really meet it?

Comment: @Randall Let $f: M^n \to N^m$ be smooth. Suppose $q\in N$ is a regular value for f  that means $df_p : T_pM \to T_qN$ is surjective for all $p\in f^{-1}(q)$ .

Comment: Right.  So why is the derivative surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential of $f$ is
$$ \nabla f(x_1,…,x_n)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2x_1&…&0 \\ \vdots & &\ddots&\\0 & 0&…&2x_n\end{pmatrix},$$
which is just zero for all points in $f^{-1}(0,…,0)$. Thus, the differential is not surjective in all of those points, hence those points are not regular, which means that $(0,…,0)$ is not a regular value.

Comment: See the definition of regular value and regular point here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)